# adding a Fix value into date column as running value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below set of data and trying add a fix value of `0.2` into date1 column

```
with d as ( 
select 76844 id_tra,53445 id_detalle_tra,'SOLIC' id_process,'21-05-26 15:36:44' date1 from dual
union
select 76844 id_tra,53446,'SOLIC','21-05-26 15:36:44' from dual
union
select 76844 id_tra,53447,'SOLIC','21-05-26 15:36:49' from dual
union
select 76844 id_tra,53448,'SOLIC','21-05-26 15:36:52' from dual )
SELECT ID_TRA,ID_DETALLE_TRA, ID_PROCESS, DATE1 ,NVL(LAG(DATE1) OVER (ORDER BY id_detalle_tra),DATE1) NEW_DATE,
NVL(LAG(DATE1) OVER (ORDER BY id_detalle_tra),DATE1) NEW_DATE1
FROM
(SELECT ID_TRA,ID_DETALLE_TRA, ID_PROCESS, to_date(DATE1,'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') date1 FROM D)
```

I have used above query for to get below results by adding 0.2 on each date1 row :

for example First date1 value is `5/26/2021 15:36:44` by adding `0.2` it will result `5/26/21 8:24:44 PM` on second row and so for each row till end adding 0.2 from previous value of each row.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you'll need hierarchical query with addition of a cross join to avoid duplicates.

```
SQL> with d as (
  2    select 76844 id_tra,53445 id_detalle_tra,'SOLIC' id_process,'21-05-26 15:36:44' date1 from dual
  3    union
  4    select 76844 id_tra,53446,'SOLIC','21-05-26 15:36:44' from dual
  5    union
  6    select 76844 id_tra,53447,'SOLIC','21-05-26 15:36:49' from dual
  7    union
  8    select 76844 id_tra,53448,'SOLIC','21-05-26 15:36:52' from dual
  9  )
 10  select id_tra,
 11    id_detalle_tra,
 12    id_process,
 13    date1,
 14    date1 + (0.2 * (column_value - 1)) new_date
 15  from
 16    (select id_tra,id_detalle_tra, id_process,
 17       to_date(date1,'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') date1 from d
 18    ) cross join
 19    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 20                        connect by level <= (select count(*) from d)
 21                      ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 22  order by id_tra, id_detalle_tra, id_process, date1, new_date;
```

which results in

```
    ID_TRA ID_DETALLE_TRA ID_PR DATE1                  NEW_DATE
---------- -------------- ----- ---------------------- ----------------------
     76844          53445 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:44 PM 05/26/2021 03:36:44 PM
     76844          53445 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:44 PM 05/26/2021 08:24:44 PM
     76844          53445 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:44 PM 05/27/2021 01:12:44 AM
     76844          53445 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:44 PM 05/27/2021 06:00:44 AM
     76844          53446 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:44 PM 05/26/2021 03:36:44 PM
     76844          53446 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:44 PM 05/26/2021 08:24:44 PM
     76844          53446 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:44 PM 05/27/2021 01:12:44 AM
     76844          53446 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:44 PM 05/27/2021 06:00:44 AM
     76844          53447 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:49 PM 05/26/2021 03:36:49 PM
     76844          53447 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:49 PM 05/26/2021 08:24:49 PM
     76844          53447 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:49 PM 05/27/2021 01:12:49 AM
     76844          53447 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:49 PM 05/27/2021 06:00:49 AM
     76844          53448 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:52 PM 05/26/2021 03:36:52 PM
     76844          53448 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:52 PM 05/26/2021 08:24:52 PM
     76844          53448 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:52 PM 05/27/2021 01:12:52 AM
     76844          53448 SOLIC 05/26/2021 03:36:52 PM 05/27/2021 06:00:52 AM

16 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: the output should be only 4 rows as mentioned in question , can  you look into the results

Comment: Which 4 rows? What are other columns doing here? How do they contribute the final result? All you posted is 4 dates as NEW_DATE column. Zero descriptive. Now that you know *how* to do it, feel free to improve it.

Comment: I totally understand what you have done is great , however can we just consider the first date value from first row and return only first 4 rows from above results u shared , not for each date in given data set

Comment: Sure. Add `where id_detalle_tra = 53445` into the inline view.